# Using a loop with Google Maps Location data

Tags: java, android, google-maps, loops

I'm using google maps android to get current location:

```
LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```

How would I construct a simple loop to produce only say every 4th currentLocation instead of every point being fed through the locationManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a loop to ignore location updates, I think you should only request location updates at the frequency you would like to receive them, otherwise the device is using all the power to get the location only to have it ignored.

You should be using the LocationClient rather than LocationManager
See the following links for how to use LocationClient
http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, android.app.PendingIntent)

vs LocationManager
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long, float, android.location.Criteria, android.app.PendingIntent)

but both provide methods to request location updates at a specific frequency via a

```
requestLocationUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1 - the right one - limit location provider querying

This should somewhat optimize battery life and is how the API was intended to be used.

Assuming you use `LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)` for obtaining current location, if you increase `minTime` four times you will effectively receive every fourth location update.

### Option 2 - the lazy one - only update map every n seconds

This will allow you to process every location received from location provider but update map only every n seconds.

You want to keep track of when you last updated map and only update if n seconds have passed.

Declarations:

```
long lastTime = -1; // no location update yet
final long delta = 15 * 1000; // fifteen seconds apart
```

In your `onLocationChanged`:

```
// common code here, do this for every location received ...
Log.d(TAG, location + "");

// this gets executed only after fifteen seconds
if (location.getTime() > lastTime + delta) {
    // update map here
    lastTime = location.getTime();
}
```

Note that this will not ensure that you get a map update precisely every fifteen seconds. You will get the first update after fifteen seconds have passed.